# action payload in the effect

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I have the following code

```
  @Effect()
  executeMission$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<featureActions.ExecuteUsedDroneMissionRequest>(featureActions.ActionTypes.ExecuteUsedDroneMissionRequest),
    withLatestFrom(this.store$.pipe(select(MissionsStoreSelectors.selectAllEntities))),
    switchMap(([action, missions]) => {
      const mission = missions[action.payload.missionId] 
      //....
    })
  );
```

Now, I have a selector which is supposed to remove this line =>
          const mission = missions[action.payload.missionId]

```
export const selectAllEntities: (state: object) => Dictionary<IMission> = featureAdapter.getSelectors(selectMissionState).selectEntities;
export const getById = () => createSelector(
  selectAllEntities,
  (entities, props) => entities[props.routeId]
);
```

but to use it, I need to add the action payload into the withLatestFrom like this

```
withLatestFrom(this.store$.pipe(select(MissionsStoreSelectors.selectById(), { missionId: action.payload.missionId }))),
```

but action is not available outside the switchMap.

Is it possible to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `concatMap`, this example comes from my post [Start using ngrx/effects for this](https://blog.angularindepth.com/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this-e0b2bd9da165)

```
 concatMap(action =>  
    of(action).pipe(
      withLatestFrom(store.pipe(select(getUserName)))
    )
  ),
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 @Effect()
  executeMission$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<featureActions.ExecuteUsedDroneMissionRequest>(featureActions.ActionTypes.ExecuteUsedDroneMissionRequest),
    withLatestFrom(
       this.store$.pipe(select(MissionsStoreSelectors.selectAllEntities)),
       (action, missions) => { mission: missions[action.payload.missionId] }
  ),
```

Something like that?

Answer (score 2):

Use switchMap to switch to the new observable's stream returned by withLatestFrom as follows:

```
@Effect()
  executeMission$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<featureActions.ExecuteUsedDroneMissionRequest>(
      featureActions.ActionTypes.ExecuteUsedDroneMissionRequest
    ),
    switchMap(action => {
      return withLatestFrom(this.store$.pipe(select(MissionsStoreSelectors.selectById(), { missionId: action.payload.missionId })))
    })
  );
```

So you have the payload as input to use it in your selector